# ASP.NET Core show Exception details in published app

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am making an ASP.NET Core application in which I want to demonstrate how important is using *app.UseExceptionHandler* in a published application because without it we can find out, for example, that the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

When I use app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in my Configure method in Startup.cs and I publish the application and run it on Windows, it shows me this:
[image]
This is exactly what I want because I can see the SQL query.

But when I run it on Linux, it shows me this:[image]
I can't expand the Info so I can't see the code behind where the exception was thrown. Anyone knows what cause this problem and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Info is the Action method of a controller.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately links to the images you posted are broken.

Comment: How is that possible? I can see them even in Inkognito mode

Comment: It seems problem on my side, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage()` method in your startup class?

Comment: Does the exception page really not contain the information? It might as well be buggy and not render correctly on some browser - might be worth a check

Comment: I checked the source code of the page and it's not there on Linux

Comment: @TemiLajumoke I have tried it and the result is the same - still I can't expand any of the list item

Comment: @MacakM the error seems to be coming from an SQL query. Have you tried using linq?

Comment: Are the pdb files available on windows and not on Linux? I suspect that's where the runtime gets the details from.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen I have pdb files on both platforms. It is the same folder that I use on Linux and Windows